# how and why is circular doubly linked lists concatenation of complexity O(1)?

Tags: concatenation, doubly-linked-list

It is given as a fact in a certain standard book that concatenation of circular doubly linked lists is of complexity O(1) and it is not the case with single or doubly linked lists. Can someone please clarify why and how this is possible...

Comment: Well, try writing the catenation code for the three cases you mentioned, and compute the asymptotic cost of each for your implementations. What results do you come up with? Do they match the claim in the book or not?

Answer (score 3):

In a circular doubly linked list, you have `head->prev` pointing to the last element. So, all you have to do is to perform the concatenation using that node's address, so O(1). Whereas, in a simple singly or doubly linked list, you'll have to traverse the list to get the last element and perform the concatenation which looks like O(n) to me.

Comment: Oh yes.. thanq.. I overlooked the doubly word.. so was of the impression that to go to the last element from the head one needs to traverse throughout  a circular linked  list.. now it makes sense with your explanation. . Thanks :)